# Changing BackgroundColor of Button within Xamarin CollectionView changes the BackgroundColor of every 8th button down. why?

Tags: xamarin, colors, collectionview

I have a Xamarin CollectionView That uses a Button (`Button x:Name="PNameButton"`) to Change the Background color of the button.
When the Button is clicked the background color changes... However - So does every 8th Button in the CollectionView.   Its as if the CollectionView renders new data every 8 or so items, and that new first button gets the changed color property.  How do I fix this?  Code Follows:

```
            <CollectionView x:Name="PairingsCollectionView" SelectionMode="Multiple" Margin="20,5,20,5"  >
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        

                        <Grid Margin="0" Padding="0,0,0,0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                
                                
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <BoxView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" Color="#333130"/>
                            <Button x:Name="PNameButton" Margin="0" Padding="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="{Binding UseColor}" Text="{Binding PDisplayName}" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" 
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
                            <BoxView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Color="#333130" Margin="0"></BoxView>
                            <Label Margin="0" Padding="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="White" FontSize="Small" 
                                HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                    <FormattedString>
                                        <Span Text="{Binding PDays, StringFormat='{0}Dy'}"/>
                                        <Span Text=" "/>
                                        <Span Text="{Binding PDay}"/>
                                    </FormattedString>
                                </Label.FormattedText>
                            </Label>
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0" Color="#333130"></BoxView>
                            <Label  Margin="0" Padding="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding PCredit, StringFormat='{0}'}" TextColor="#F57BFA" FontSize="Small" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Color="#333130" Margin="0"></BoxView>
                            <Label Margin="0" Padding="0,0,0,0"  Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding PFlightTime, StringFormat='{0}'}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Small" 
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Color="#333130" Margin="0"/>
                            <Label Margin="0" Padding="0,0,0,0"  Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding PRegionType, StringFormat='{0}'}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Color="#333130"  Margin="0"/>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="IsSelectedCheckbox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" IsChecked="{Binding PIsSelected}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            

                            <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Color="LightGray"></BoxView>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="{Binding PDateModified}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" 
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Color="LightGray" ></BoxView>
                            
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Text="{Binding PLayovers}"
                            TextColor="Coral" FontAttributes="Bold"  FontSize="17" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" />


                            <WebView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" BackgroundColor="#333130" 
                                     MinimumHeightRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                     HeightRequest="{Binding PWebViewHeight}" >
                                <WebView.Source>
                                    <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding PAllText}"/>
                                </WebView.Source>
                                
                            </WebView>
                                                 
                        </Grid>

                        
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

And in the Code Behind:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string ChkVal = "";
        bool compareBool = false;
        bool currentState = false;
        Color buttonColer;
        string ColorHexVal;
        int i = 0;



        var thisButton = sender as Button;
        

        buttonColer = thisButton.BackgroundColor;
        ColorHexVal = buttonColer.ToHex();
        if (buttonColer != Color.FromHex("#F7F75A"))  
        {   
            currentState = true;
        }
        else
        {
            currentState = false;
        }
        
        var PairingItem = ((Button)sender).Parent.BindingContext as Pairings;
        compareBool = App.DatabaseNA.GetIsSelected(PairingItem.PID);


        if (!compareBool == true)
            {

            thisButton.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#46AE3C"); 
        }
            else
            {

            thisButton.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#F7F75A");

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Alert", ex.InnerException.ToString(), "OK"); //await 

    }

}
```

Again - Thank You!!!
The code works great and sets the Background color of the button...  The problem is - It sets the Background Color of every Button about 8 items down.

Thanks

Comment: CV is virtualized - it is caching UI controls internally for performance.  This is why you should be using data binding to dynamically set UI properties.  Directly modifying the UI elements like you are doing is screwing with the underlying virtualization mechanism.

Comment: Thank You, Thank You Jason !!! That is what I was thinking is happening.    I tried Databinding the color.  As you can see - BackgroundColor="{Binding UseColor}" And that works when the CollectionView loads the first time.  The collectionview needs to be rebound when someone selects an item or clicks the button.  It just worked nicer with button click event.

Comment: do the objects in your `ItemsSource` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Jason - Thank You!  Are you saying I can put OnPropertyChanged on an Object that is databound to a database.  Wow - MY brain hurts.  I know my code is not good, but...  The CollectionView Gets its DataSource from a Sqlite Database,  When a user clicks the button - The click event changes a "IsSelected" Database Field in the database field - It also changes the background color of the button.   NOTE: when the CollectionView initially loads those buttons are databound {Binding IsSelected} to change the color.  How would I implement an OnPropertyChanged.?  Thank You - I gotta think on this - wow!

Comment: if you want your UI to update when a property on an object changes, that object needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the setter for the property needs to call `PropertyChanged`.   INPC is exhaustively documented